# Any homeomorphism from the boundary of a disc to itself can be extended to a homeomorphism of the whole disc

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a disc. We are given a homeomorphism $f:∂A\to ∂A$ and we want to extend it to a homeomorphism $g:A\to A$. If it is true that *the union of two homeomorphisms is a homeomorphism* (which I think is true because by the pasting lemma the union is continuous and so as its inverse and also it's a bijection) then $h:A\to A$ such that $h(x)=x$ whenever $x\in A\setminus ∂A$ and $h(x)=f(x)$ whenever $x\in ∂A$ is a homeomorphism.

**Question:** Obviously there is something wrong because my book (Armstrong, Topology) gives a slightly more complicated proof. So where is the mistake? Or the book asks for something different?

Comment: Your $h$ is continuous only if the $f$ that you started with is the identity.

Comment: The $h$ you defined will not be continuous on the boundary, unless $g = \operatorname{id}$.

Comment: For example, try to see what happens if $f(x)=-x$.

Comment: Oops, I made a typo. Editing it.

Answer (score 3):

Try to extend it with: $F(x):=||x||f(x/||x||)$ and $F(0):=0$ (you're basically thinking the disk as the union of all the possible concentric spheres inside it plus its center).

Comment: I don't know linear algebra. But $x/||x||$ is the unit vector, right?
If $A\subset \Bbb{R}^2$ with radius $2$ and center $(0,0)$, what is $F((0,1/2))$?

Comment: It's $1/2f(0,1)$

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the pasting lemma (if I think of the same pasting lemma...) reguires the two sets to be closed simultaneously, I mean, if there are two sets $A$ and $B$ and $f:A\to Y$, $g:B\to Y$ are continuous and coinside on $A\cap B$ and both $A$ and $B$ are closed, then $h:A\cup B\to Y$ defined by $h(x) = f(x)$ when $x\in A$ and $h(x) = g(x)$ when $x\in B$ is continuous 
(you can show this by proving that the preimage of any closed in $Y$ set under $h$ is closed in $A\cup B$). In your case, the boundary is closed, but the complement is open... So it seems to me...